# Вытащить переменные из многовложенного массива PHP

Tags: php, json

Привет всем.
Есть массив полученный из json путем json_decode

```
    stdClass Object
(
    [center_lat] => 51.785635290118
    [center_lng] => 55.1109775
    [zoom] => 16
    [type] => map
    [marks] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [content] => 
                    [type] => Point
                    [coords] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 51.785721792459
                            [1] => 55.111133068123
                        )

                    [circle_size] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

Мне нужно вытащить координаты и присвоить им переменные.
Увы во всех примерах есть только обращение к значению через `$data->name`.
Это сработает для `center_lat`, `center_lng`, `zoom`, `type`.
А вот как получить именно координаты `coords`, я не знаю.

Подскажите кто в курсе, а то вложенность массива из меня всю душу вытрясло?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, так

```
$std = new stdclass();

$coord = new stdclass();
$coord->coords = [2, 5];

$std->marks = [
    $coord
    ];

var_dump($std->marks[0]->coords[0]);
```

Но в вашем случае, вроде так

```
$object->marks[0]->coords[0];
```